# Germany tax class residence permit valid anmeldung

Tags: income-tax, tax-deduction, germany

I was in Germany last year for more than six months and I have a valid RP as well.
Now, I am planning to move back to Germany for just 2 months for a work assignment under Short-term WP.

Now my question is since I do not need to do anmeldung / local registration since the period of stay is less than 3 months. So, If I don't register, which tax-class would I fall under?
Will it be tax-class I, which I used to be under earlier when I left Germany last year and since I have a valid RP?

Or

Would I fall under tax-class VI? because I remember when last time I entered Germany, initially I was under tax-class6 till the time I did not apply for RP.

and other questions is? since I am moving after 175 days to Germany again, would my RP become alive again as I entered Germany or I require the Anmeldung to make sure it does not get expire after 5 days. as It is approaching the time-limit of 180 days.

thanks
Ankit